# compare functionality issue asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to compare two string and get both duplicate and original value  .
On calling chkDuplicateValue function i need to get both duplicate and original in the return value ?
, acts as delimeter for both the string .
Dim oldStr As String = "test1,test2,test"
Dim newStr As String = "test,test53"
Example out put : Original Value :test1,test2,test,test53  duplicate Value : test

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim oldStr As String = "test1,test2,test"
Dim newStr As String = "test,test53"
Dim refinedString As String = chkDuplicateValue(newStr, oldStr)
```

'On calling this function i need to get both duplicate and original in the return value ?

```
Response.Write("Original Value" & refinedString(0))
Response.Write("duplicate Value" & refinedString(1))
'Example out put : Original Value :test1,test2,test,test53  duplicate Value : test
End Sub

Function chkDuplicateValue(ByVal newStr As String, ByVal oldStr As String) As String
    Dim duplicate As String = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have experience with Linq?

Comment: "Original value" seems like a misnomer here.

Answer (score 0):

```
return oldStr.Split(',').Union(newStr.Spit(','));
```

and if that doesn't work using the Join linq extension method

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq **Intersect** to return duplicates and **Union** to return Distinctlist. Pass **newStr ByRef**, so, that unduplicated string will be returned on **newStr**. Also, remeber to reference **System.Linq**

```
Function chkDuplicateValue(ByRef newStr As String, ByVal oldStr As String) As String
     Dim duplicate As String = ""
     duplicate = String.Join(",",(newStr.Split(',').Intersect(oldStr.Split(','))).ToArray())
     newStr = String.Join(",",(newStr.Split(',').Union(oldStr.Split(','))).ToArray())
     return uplicate
End Function
```